# more wattage bulb in my pulsar 150cc 2016 model

Tags: motorcycle, headlight

I bought pulsar 150dtsi couple months back...though it have 12 volt 7ah battery...its headlight performance is not good as i expected specially on highways.. n in total dark areas of my city..its halogen bulb is of only 35/35watt.. so just want to knwo that by not doing anything like changing wiring or upgrading coil or magnets..can i just change my stock bulb to 55watt halogen bulb?..( no HID or LED)
Is it possible to do so?... Or my wiring will short n fuse will get defused or my headlight reflector will burn due to extra 20watt heat?... Please anyone know the answer tell me....thanks in advance...as my previous bike( Hero Honda Glamour kick start).. had just 2.5ah battery so nothing was possible that time...but here in case of pulsar a 55watt bulb will be placed?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your bike isn't capable of generating enough power for a 55w headlight bulb. If you installed one, you'd likely have problems with your battery going flat. You would need to upgrade the stator, which is a common enough modification.

http://www.team-bhp.com/forum/motorbikes/44428-headlight-upgrade-bajaj-pulsar-150-dtsi.html